# FTP corrupted ZIP

Tags: python, zip, ftplib

When I use this code to download a zip file from and FTP server it comes back corrupted. Anyone know why?

```
from ftplib import FTP
import getpass

user = raw_input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass()
host = raw_input('Host:')
ftp = FTP(host,user,password)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
f_file = raw_input('What is the name of the file you would like to download? ')
print 'Opening local file...'
l_file = open(f_file, 'w')
print "Getting", f_file
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f_file, l_file.write)
print "Closing", f_file
l_file.close()
print 'Closing FTP connection'
ftp.close()
```

Comment: Please post your code inline.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you're writing the local copy in ASCII mode, not binary mode, thereby changing all `0A` bytes into `0D0A` (LF to CRLF), corrupting the binary file.

Try again using `l_file = open(f_file, 'wb')`.

Comment: Yep, mode write + binary. Thx.